# Install mamp pro php7

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I downloaded the php 7 folder from the mamp download-pages and copied it in mamp/bin/php but it doesn't show up in my mamp pro php selection (after restart). Anybody had same issue?

Comment: works fine. whats in the folder "php7.0.0"?

Comment: I have the same issue, anyone help? using MAMP Pro 3.3, and i have copied `php7.0.12` folder on `mamp/bin/php`

Comment: I am having same issue.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Same question..